# Generalization of Chernoff bound to Bernoulli schemes

Tags: sampling, proportion, bernoulli-distribution

I have this (I think) simple problem, which I guess is just a generalization of the Chernoff bound to Bernoulli schemes. Assume I have a bowl with N balls with R different colors. The balls are not necessarily evenly distributed. How many balls do I need to sample (with replacement) in order to decide with confidence % C which color occurs most often in the bowl? Well, that depends on the distribution of course.

Let us assume that $0 < \text{prop(most_often)} \leq 1$ denotes the proportion of the most often occuring color. Now, for $R = 2$ (and thus $\text{prop(most_often)} \geq \frac{1}{2}$) we can plug these values into the Chernoff bound. But can that be generalized to $R \geq 3$?

Comment: Why Chernoff bound rather than exact computation?

Comment: That is fine, too. But I don't know how to compute exactly. Please enlighten me ;-)